# Docusign anchor Tag conditional show or hide and dynamic calculation

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use docusign for below scenerio using c#.

Series                          Bank Account Number   Amount of Capital
•   Series 1 – Test1 Fund            1234USD01        \tbx1_1_text\
•   Series 1 – Test2 Fund            1234USD02        \tbx2_1_text\
•   Series 2 – Test1 Fund            332USD01         \tbx3_1_text\
                      Total Amount of Subscription:   \tbx4_1_text\

1. Subscriber Information.
   (a) Record Name and Address of Subscriber.
   \tbx4_1_text\
   (b) Email Address:  \tbx4_1_text\
   (c) Tax Status.  Please indicate below whether Subscriber is exempt from U.S. federal income taxation:
   \cb1_1_yes\ tax-exempt
   \cb2_1_no\  not tax exempt
   If tax-exempt, please indicate the basis on which Subscriber is exempt from U.S. federal income taxation: \tbx5_1_text\

I wanted to prepopulate the the text boxes from database and user also can edit values in those textboxes. 
if user enter or change the values in tbx1,tbx2,tbx3 then summation of those should be displayed in tbx4. all the three textboxes is required and only number should be allowed to enter.

There is a checkbox field if user selected the cb1_1 then tbx5_1 is required otherwise tbx5_1 should be readonly.

can you help me how to achieve this functionality using anchor tags.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to make your question(s) a little more clear?  I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but yes you can make any field you want required (whether it uses anchor tags for location or not) and yes you can do things like add two field values and display the result in a third field.  You can use the Formula fields for that, search the API documentation.  You can also have Conditional DocuSign fields as well.

Comment: Sounds like OP wants the document to run a calculation and display the resultant calculation in another field. I don't think this is possible though.

Comment: I dont know, how to achieve this in docusign. This is possible using echosign and i am doing some required poc if all these things are possible in docusign or not for making a decision on using docusign. but seems like we cant...